# How to redirect page without nesting the url in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom v5 for routing in my application. In some case I have route like this:

```
checkup/step-1/:id
checkup/step-2/:id
checkup/step-3/:id
```

For example, I'm at `checkup/step-1/:id` so I want to redirect from there to `checkup/step-2/:id`. To redirect I use `hisory.push()`. But the result is become like this:

```
checkup/step-1/:id/checkup/step-2/:id
```

But my expected result is:

```
checkup/step-2/:id
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a relevant [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? We can't really help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: add / at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` at the start. 
For Example:

```
history.push('/checkup/step-2/:id')
```

instead of

```
history.push('checkup/step-2/:id')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this brings out the result I expected sir

Comment: @Raazescythe please consider accepting the answer if it works 

Comment: I couldn't do it for the last 5 minutes. But now I can, thank you sirr

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Redirect` component provided by react-router-dom

eg:

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
function MyComponent (){
  return (
    <>
      {condition && <Redirect to='/your-desire-path'/>}
      <MyOtherStaff/>
    </>
  )
}
```